# How to apply different class to all previous, current and all next elements using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on range slider for my website. I am stuck in to make it possible that on clicking specific box all previous steps gets applied with class ".previous" and all steps next to current one get applied with ".next" class, which have different styling for previous steps and next steps, according to the data-label value of that specific div. Lets take an example for a simple scenario if I click on step 7 then step 5 and 6 gets red, and step 8 and 9 gets grey, if I click on step 9 all previous gets applied with ".previous" class. In simple words all steps having number greater than current active step get applied with ".next" class and all those having number less then current active gets applied with ".previous" class .Attached is the source code, Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

```js
const rangeSlider = document.querySelector('#price_slider');
rangeSlider.addEventListener("input", rangeScript);
const customProgress = document.querySelector('#customProgress');

for (let i = 0; i < rangeSlider.max - rangeSlider.min; i++) {
  const step = document.createElement('div');
  step.classList.add('step');
  step.setAttribute('data-label', +rangeSlider.min + i + 1);
  step.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let val = e.target.dataset.label;
    document.querySelector('#price_slider').value = val
    rangeScript({
      target: rangeSlider
    })
  })
  customProgress.appendChild(step);
}

customProgress.querySelector(`.step[data-label="${rangeSlider.value}"]`)
  .classList.add('current')

function rangeScript(e) {
  const target = document.getElementById('progress');
  let newValue = parseInt(e.target.value);
  const currentStep = customProgress.querySelector(`.step.current`);
  if (currentStep) {
    currentStep.classList.remove('current');
  }
  nextStep = customProgress.querySelector(`.step[data-label="${newValue}"]`);
  if (nextStep) {
    nextStep.classList.add('current')
  
  }
}
```

```css
#customProgress {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;

  margin-top: 44px;
}

.step {
  position: relative;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}

.step::after {
  content: attr(data-label);
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.5em;
  right: -0.25em;
}

.step ~ .current,
.step.current {
  background: #a6983e;
}
.previous {
  background: red;
}
.next {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<div id="customProgress"></div>
  <div id="progress" style="width: 100%">
     <input id="price_slider" type="range" min="4" max="9" value="" style="display:none" />
 </div>
```

Comment: Loop over all step elements, assign the class `previous` as long as the current element is not that of your current step, and assign the `next` class for those that come after …? You could f.e. simply “toggle” from one class to the other, by storing it in a variable. `classToAssign = 'previous'`, and then when you go past your current element with the loop, you change that to `classToAssign = 'next'`

Comment: (It could of course also be done with only a single class `current` set on the current element, and no `previous`/`next` at all … keyword _general sibling combinator_.)

Comment: @CBroe Well, It is really good elaborated by you. Highly appreciate your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
const rangeSlider = document.querySelector('#price_slider');
rangeSlider.addEventListener("input", rangeScript);
const customProgress = document.querySelector('#customProgress');

for (let i = 0; i < rangeSlider.max - rangeSlider.min; i++) {
  const step = document.createElement('div');
  step.classList.add('step');
  step.setAttribute('data-label', +rangeSlider.min + i + 1);
  step.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let val = e.target.dataset.label;
    document.querySelector('#price_slider').value = val
    rangeScript({
      target: rangeSlider
    })
  })
  customProgress.appendChild(step);
}

customProgress.querySelector(`.step[data-label="${rangeSlider.value}"]`)
  .classList.add('current')

function rangeScript(e) {
  const target = document.getElementById('progress');
  let newValue = parseInt(e.target.value);
  const currentStep = customProgress.querySelector(`.step.current`);
  if (currentStep) {
    currentStep.classList.remove('current');
  }
  nextStep = customProgress.querySelector(`.step[data-label="${newValue}"]`);
  if (nextStep) {
    nextStep.classList.add('current')
  
  }
}
```

```css
#customProgress {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;

  margin-top: 44px;
}

.step {
  position: relative;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}

.step::after {
  content: attr(data-label);
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.5em;
  right: -0.25em;
}

.step ~ .current,
.step.current {
  background: #a6983e;
}
.step {
  background: green;
}
.current ~ div {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="customProgress"></div>
  <div id="progress" style="width: 100%">
     <input id="price_slider" type="range" min="4" max="9" value="" style="display:none" />
 </div>
```

Comment: Well you just made it look so simple. I appreciate your effort.!